# How to set Azure Worker Role service configuration in build definition

Tags: c#, azure, azure-worker-roles, continuous-deployment, azure-devops

I'm setting up a continuous deployment build in Visual Studio Online for a Azure worker role.  I have multiple service configurations to support the various environments in my Azure subscription.

[image]

I'm using the GitContinuousDeploymentTemplate.12.xaml build definition

[image]

I've tried to set the "Path To Deployment Settings" to my *.azurePubxml file.  When the build completes and deploys it is using the values for the "Cloud" service configuration rather than the service configuration that was set in my *.azurePubxml file.

[image]

Here is a snippet from my *.azurePubxml file with the solution and service configuration settings.

[image]

Comment: Would it be possible to post your MSBUILD full log?  I've had some luck customizing the Git template for odd-but-should-work scenarios, but not this exact one.  I have, however, solved this back before MSBUILD/VS allowed you to have multiple .cscfgs.  With the logs, I can probably mash it all together and get you a solution.